# Flyway connection failing, connecting using psql command line works fine

Tags: docker, flyway

I have a docker service for postgres that is running fine:

```
postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:13.0-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=false
      - POSTGRES_DB=yola
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password123
```

I can connect fine using terminal like this:

```
export PGPASSWORD=password123; psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d yola -U postgres
```

Now when I try and run flyway I get a connection problem.
I tried doing both `0.0.0.0` and `localhost` and the docker image name `yola_postgres_1`.

I still get this error running the following command:

```
docker run --rm -v /path/to/folder/migrations:/flyway/sql flyway/flyway -url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yola -user=postgres -password=password123 info
```

> ERROR: Unable to obtain connection from database
> (jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yola) for user 'postgres':
> Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port
> are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- SQL State  : 08001 Error Code : 0 Message    : Connection to
> localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct
> and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
>
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to
> localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct
> and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. Caused by:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: What's the connection between the docker image of postgres and the docker image with flyway? Because it seems that the docker-flyway is using localhost (which means inside the docker image with flyway, not your localhost) instead of using the address of the docker-postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Problem

You have PostgreSQL running in one container and Flyway in another, and `localhost` is per container, so Flyway isn't communicating with PostgreSQL

#### A Solution

You already map `5432` in PostgreSQL to `5432` on the host, so you can add `--network=host` to the `docker run` command for the Flyway container which makes `localhost` match that of the host

This will make your current set up work, and you could then look into container networking if you want your containers to communicate with each other directly, not through the host

Comment: I use docker-compose for my postgres, does it have a network option?

Comment: @Blankman You need to set `--network=host` on the `docker run` command for the Flyway container - I'll update the answer to make this clearer. To answer your question however, yes, [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode) is the documentation for setting the network in a compose file. The property is called `network_mode`

Comment: Host networking shouldn't be the normal way to communicate between containers.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes a more standard approach, using the database container's Compose service name `postgres` as a host name.